# In Svelte app error of Failed to load module script occurs

Tags: javascript, svelte, netlify

I deployed my Svelte application(Static webpage) on Netlify and tried launching it from Google Chrome. I see app is loading, however there is nothing displayed on the browser. Upon checking on browser console , I could see this error:

`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.` for `(main.js)` file.

URL I'm trying to access is : https://crypto-valid-svelte.netlify.app/

Are there any work-arounds or solutions to this issue? If anyone knows how to resolve it Please let me know.

`index.html` - produced after running `npm run dev` locally is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Crypto Validator</title>
  <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/dist/boxicons.js"></script> -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/public/global.css'>
  <!-- <link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/bundle.css'> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- <script defer src='/build/bundle.js'></script> -->
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried to make changes in `index.html` page according to some forums but no expectation has been met yet.
**Github repository link is** **https://github.com/aa98-45556443355666/crypto_validator--**
[image]

### **It should look like**

[image]